# JPG / PNG Thumbnail

Tags: png, jpeg, thumbnails

So let's say I have a JPEG file of 4mb~ and I don't want to read it all to create a preview. Is there a way to skip reading some cols/rows? I tried for example Irfanview Thumbnails, but that applications read the entire file first, then creates the thumbnail, so I was thinking of doing a custom app to achieve this.

If I don't care about quality or artifacts, is this possible? The image resides in local / private network filesystem.

Comment: Let me get this streight, you don't want to **read** the entire file? You want to read and parse only parts of it? This is not possible.

Comment: Why is not possible? Can you elaborate an explanation?

Comment: You can use progressive encoding when you create the image to enable this (a low res version can be created from the start of the image file), and some image file formats support embedding a thumbnail view too. Both of these are options at the time the file was written though.

Comment: @Veehmot, hmm, I might have been a little hasty. Generally it's not possible because JPEG marker payload is variably sized. Admittedly each marker specifies it's own size, but it'd be difficult to know which markers should be discarded. I.e. marker is not necessarily a row or a column.

Comment: @Gleno: If I discard random markers, the resulting image will have "holes" but still conserve the main structure? I.e. something like the noise filter.

Comment: @Veehmot, After some research I now think it's possible to build a system that doesn't parse all markers for both baseline and progressive JPEGs to generate thumbs, but you still need to read all of the data into memory, which would still take IO time. Compared to loading 4MB JPEG into memory, the actual processing would intuitively take a long shorter; so we are at best talking about second-order optimization, and at worst - since this may take you some time to get working - a major slowdown...

Comment: @Gleno: The aspect that I wanted to avoid was reading all the data, and now you tell me that it's not possible. But anyway, thanks for the research!

Comment: @Gleno: I'm more concerned about data read, because the application will be targeted at networks files... That's why I was thinking about seeking specific parts of the file to avoid downloading the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

If the JPEG image has an embedded (EXIF) thumbnail, you can read that much faster than reading the whole file. The thumbnail image is usually less than 24K bytes. Typical phones and digital cameras embed a 160x120 image. If this is large enough for your purposes and you're working with photos, then you have a solution. For the case where you don't have an embedded thumbnail or need one at a higher resolution, you will need to read the entire file contents unless it is stored as a progressive image (as mentioned above). The quickest way to generate a thumbnail is to use only the DC values for each MCU and you will end up with a 1/64th image (1/8th in x and y directions). This allows you to skip the expensive DCT and color conversion steps for the entire image.